# High error rate in multi-layer feedforward neurolab network

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, feed-forward, multi-layer

Why is my network showing me a high error?
I need to follow these rules -

```
multi-layer feedforward (2 inputs, 1 output);
```

the first input has 262144 values (from 0 to 256) and 
the second 262144 (from 0 to 1024).

I'm using only one hidden layer. My error is something like this:

```
Epoch: 1; Error: 2816810148.1; 
Epoch: 2; Error: 2814260288.59; 
Epoch: 3; Error: 2813602739.7; 
Epoch: 4; Error: 2813385229.99; 
Epoch: 5; Error: 2813308095.39;
```

Comment: use proper formatting

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your input for first and second column. Then de-normalize your output. Also consider scaling your second column to be closer in values to first column. It will give your better error surface.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your network is working exactly as intended. On every epoch, the error has come down. The network initialises with a random "guess" and then moves from there - it has no foresight into the answer it must generate. With 250K+ inputs of values that go into the 1000s, it's not difficult to imagine that your error would be so high (you haven't stated what your error metric is). It's a lot of data, it's going to take a lot of epochs (1000s minimum) to get something useful. Between epoch 1 and 2 your error, whatever unit that may be, has come down by 2.5 million points. I'd say that was some improvement. Have you left it running for a few hours to see whether it might be able to solve this problem within a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Yes, indeed it should run 2000 epochs, but at epochs 16-20, the error stops decreasing. The output  has 262144 values (from 0 to 256), and my error goal is "0.0001".